Intermittently getting Blob not found even if it exists
I am reading the content of text file in Blob Storage as below. Content is read perfectly fine when requests are not concurrent. But when multiple requests are sent at once, I am getting Null as response which means blobClient.ExistsAsync() is returning false even when the file is there. Is there anything wrong with the way I am reading or any way to handle concurrency issues?
/// <summary>
/// Extracts the Text content from a file in the Blob Storage.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="blobContainerName">The name of the Container in which the file is present.</param>
/// <param name="blobName">The name of the file to be Read.</param>
/// <returns>
/// File is Present - The Content of the Text File; 
/// File is Empty - An Empty String; 
/// File Not Found - null</returns>

public async Task<string> ReadTextFileFromBlob(string blobContainerName, string blobName)
    {
    // Create a BlobServiceClient using account details
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = _blobServiceClient;

    // Get the container client
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);

    // Get the blob client
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    // Check if the blob exists
    if (!await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
    {
        // Return null if the blob does not exist
        return null;
    }
    // Download the blob content as a stream
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);

        // Check if the content is empty
        if (memoryStream.Length == 0)
        {
            // Return null if the content is empty
            return "";
        }
        // Convert the stream to a string
        string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

        return content;
    }
}

I tried going through documentation but could not find solution. I searched over the internet but still could not find anything. I am expecting it to support multiple read requests to same text file in blob storage concurrently.


I am expecting it to support multiple read requests to same text file in blob storage concurrently.

You can use the below code to read a same text file from Azure Blob Storage using multiple requests concurrently
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BlobStorageService
{
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

    public BlobStorageService(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }
    public async Task<string> ReadTextFileFromBlobAsync(string blobContainerName, string blobName)
    {
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        // Check if the blob exists and log the result
        bool blobExists = await blobClient.ExistsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Blob Exists: {blobExists}");

        if (!blobExists)
        {
            // Return null if the blob does not exist
            return null;
        }

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);

            if (memoryStream.Length == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0; 
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return content;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "zzzz"; // Replace with your connection string
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var blobStorageService = new BlobStorageService(blobServiceClient);

        string blobContainerName = "data"; 
        string blobName = "file1.txt"; 

        var tasks = new Task<string>[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = blobStorageService.ReadTextFileFromBlobAsync(blobContainerName, blobName);
        }
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
            }
            else if (result == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File content:");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}

The above code checks if the blob exists and print the result. It then downloads the blob content to a MemoryStream reads the content of the MemoryStream as a string and returns the string content.
In main function, It creates an instance of BlobServiceClient using the connection string to the Azure storage account, creates an instance of BlobStorageService using the BlobServiceClient instance, and calls the ReadTextFileFromBlobAsync method for each task.
Output:
Blob Exists: True
Blob Exists: True
Blob Exists: True
Blob Exists: True
Blob Exists: True
File content:
The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.
File content:
The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.
File content:
The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.
File content:
The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.
File content:
The sun dipped below the horizon, painting the sky in hues of orange and pink as the evening unfolded. The soft rustling of leaves in the gentle breeze created a soothing symphony, blending with the distant hum of city life. A family of ducks glided gracefully across the tranquil lake, their reflections shimmering on the still water. Nearby, the scent of blooming jasmine filled the air, mingling with the earthy aroma of freshly mowed grass. As night began to fall, stars started to twinkle, casting their celestial glow over the serene landscape, inviting a sense of calm and wonder.



How does this answer the question?

How is this code different from the original code?

I used the above code to check op requirements

Is there problem with code @Magnus and @keuleJ?

In my environment it worked and executed successfully and I can be able to read the same text file with multiple requests concurrently.

So your answer is essentially that you are unable to reproduce the issue.

You can see here my output: https://i.imgur.com/NM119d1.png @Magnus

I reproduced the code in my environment and got the above result with commented Screenshot.

@Magnus Added my output screenshot in answer.

I used Azure blob storage in my project for downloading product images from Azure. I didn't face any concurrency issues. I put my code snippet here. Hope it will work for you.
 public async Task<string> DownloadImageFromBlobStorageAsync(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a BlobServiceClient object using the connection string
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);

            // Get a reference to the container where the images are stored
            var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_containerName);

            // Get a reference to the blob (image) using the provided filename
            var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            // Download the blob's content as a stream
            var blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

            // Read the stream into a byte array
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await blobDownloadInfo.Value.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                // Convert the byte array to a Base64 string
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions that occur during the download process
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while downloading the image: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

}

